# Repositioning a menu in CSS (using lists)

Tags: css, menu, positioning

I'm having trouble repositioning the menu on this to a place of my liking. How would I be able to take the entire list and position it on the page where I would want it to be? Sorry for a simple question, I'm not very experienced.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    .menu {
        list-style: none;
        font-family: "futura", sans-serif;
    }
     .menu li {
        float: left;
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:link {
        color: grey;
     }
    a:hover {
        color: white;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: darkgrey;
    }
    .menu li:first-child {
        border: none;
    }
    div.title {
        float: left;
        font-family: "futura", sans-serif;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="title">Dan's Cupcakes</div>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://blah.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ilovetoeatgrapes.com">Cupcakes</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://thehouseisonfire.com">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://cars.com">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you want to place the menu ??

Anyways I 've edited something and provided you with the jsfiddle of it. See if it is the way you want it to appear.

You just have to change the margin values for the menu css.

```
    .menu {
margin: top_position, right_position, bottom_position, left_position;
}



http://jsfiddle.net/DGjG9/
```

See that link and come to a decision

Answer (score 0):

here's a link to learn about positioning elements with css.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

There's several ways to do it. Depending where you want it to show on the screen, is how to determine which method to use.

Comment: Don't share http://w3schools.com links...check this out... http://www.w3fools.com